# Android custom camera app retake often crashes

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, surfaceholder

I am developing my own custom camera app,while running the application if I click the **capture** button my camera will capture the current position.what I actually need is  retaking a photo whenever I need.But if I click the **retake(take photo)** button the app will crash.Here I attached my code below.So any one please help me to resolve the error.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.camera1;



import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

       private Camera cameraObject;
       private ShowCamera showCamera;
       private ImageView pic;
       private Button takePhotoButton;
       public static Camera isCameraAvailiable(){
          Camera object = null;
          try {

             object = Camera.open(); 
          }
          catch (Exception e){
          }
          return object; 
       }

       private PictureCallback capturedIt = new PictureCallback() {

          @Override
          public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

          Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data , 0, data .length);
          if(bitmap==null){
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
          else
          {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
          }
          cameraObject.release();
       }
    };

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    
          takePhotoButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_takephoto);
          cameraObject = isCameraAvailiable();
          showCamera = new ShowCamera(this, cameraObject);
          FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
          preview.addView(showCamera);



          takePhotoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  cameraObject = isCameraAvailiable();

                  cameraObject.stopPreview();
                    showCamera = new ShowCamera(getApplicationContext(), cameraObject);
                      FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
                      preview.addView(showCamera);
            }
        });

       }
       public void snapIt(View view){
          cameraObject.takePicture(null, null, capturedIt);
       }

       @Override
       public void onPause(){
           super.onPause();
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
          getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
          return true;
       }
    }
```

**ShowCamera.java**

```
package com.example.camera1;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class ShowCamera extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

       private SurfaceHolder holdMe;
       private Camera theCamera;

       public ShowCamera(Context context,Camera camera) {
          super(context);
          theCamera = camera;
          holdMe = getHolder();
          holdMe.addCallback(this);
       }

       @Override
       public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
       }

       @Override
       public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
          try   {
              theCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
             theCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
             theCamera.startPreview(); 
          } catch (IOException e) {
          }
       }

       @Override
       public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {

           theCamera.stopPreview(); 
       }

    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="0.30"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

         <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp" />

         <RelativeLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/button_capture"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:onClick="snapIt"
                 android:text="@string/Capture" />

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/button_takephoto"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/button_capture"
                 android:text="Take Photo" />
         </RelativeLayout>

   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason is you called `cameraObject.release();` in `onPictureTaken`. You can remove it. And, don't forget to call `startPreview()` again.

Because:

> This method is only valid when preview is active (after
>   startPreview()). Preview will be stopped after the image is taken;
>   callers must call startPreview() again if they want to re-start
>   preview or take more pictures. This should not be called between
>   start() and stop().
>
> After calling this method, you must not call startPreview() or take
>   another picture until the JPEG callback has returned.

Comment: after I commented `cameraObject.release();` this line in `PictureCallback` and also `cameraObject.stopPreview();` in `takePhotoButton.setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l)` if i click take photo the app won't crash but no changes in app(captured image is still there in camera screen).

Comment: Have you called startPreview()? After taking one picture, you have to call startPreview again for more.

Comment: I am using these set of code for again capturing a image  `showCamera = new ShowCamera(getApplicationContext(), cameraObject);
          FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
          preview.addView(showCamera);`

Comment: ShowCamera.java class contains `theCamera.startPreview();` inside `surfaceCreated()` method.

Comment: You don't need to write code for the new capturing. Just re-use the code you've written to activate the preview again.

Comment: now I called only `cameraObject.startPreview();` for retake it is working good..I can retake many times as per I need.

Comment: @ yushulx I have one question,I tried   to capture a image from my front camera when press the retake button.so I called `cameraObject.open(1);` before calling `cameraObject.startPreview();` but the app crashed.

Comment: could you start a new question and post your crash log?

Answer (score 0):

```
cameraObject.release();
```

Remove this line from tour `PictureCallback`. Now you know reason your app crash is quite straight to me , you are not start `camera` and `preview`  also after you capture image. `Preview` is something stop after you call `PictureCallback` ,you have resume it manually.

IF you dont want to manage this thing then i can advise you to use [cwac-camera](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera) library which is simply awesome. All you need to do is  extend your Fragment by [`CameraFragment`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/blob/master/camera/src/com/commonsware/cwac/camera/CameraFragment.java) and it will take your responsibility to manage this stuff .

Enjoy !